# Pitfalls of using LoadControl in the Load event

Tags: asp.net

I use LoadControl method in Load event quite extensively. However I haven’t observed any problems yet, I’m afraid of what [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ecy7tf.aspx) says:

> When you load a control into a container control, the container
>   raises all of the added control's events until it has caught up to the
>   current event. However, the added control **does not catch up with
>   postback data processing**. For an added control to participate in
>   postback data processing, including validation, the control must be
>   added in the Init event rather than in the Load event.

What does it actually mean?

Are there any other pitfalls when loading a control in the Load event?

Comment: The ViewState should not make problems even if it's loaded before load event. This is covered by: "_raises all of the added control's events until it has caught up to the current event_".
But i think you could get problems with raising custom events in your UserControl. Check it.

Comment: Can is ask why you need to use page's load event? Btw, cannot detect problems with custom events if the controls is added during load.

Comment: Forms data are not loaded into controls in Init event. It's a bit inconvenience to access HttpContext.Current.Request.Form directly. Good point with custom events, I will check it.

Comment: One area that can catch you out is the order of adding the control to the control tree and setting properties on that control - again this is related to ViewState.  If you set properties on the control before you add it to the control tree then the property you have set (say the Text property) does not get added to the viewstate.  However if you set the property after adding it to the Controls tree then it does get added to viewstate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That bit of MSDN documentation is (mostly) wrong. As you've discovered, postback data processing and validation work even if you dynamically add controls in the `Load` event.

Here are the stages of the ASP.NET page life cycle that are relevant to this question:

1. Raise the `Init` event.
2. *Postbacks:* Load view state and control state.
3. *Postbacks:* Load posted form data (first attempt).
4. Raise the `Load` event.
5. *Postbacks:* Load posted form data (second attempt).
6. *Postbacks:* Validate the form and raise the postback event.

The documentation is correct when it says that "the added control does not catch up with postback data processing". But it overlooks the fact that there are **two** attempts to load posted form data, once before the `Load` event and once after. Thus, if you dynamically add a control in the `Load` event, it *will* be populated with posted form data by the time the postback event (such as `submitButton_Click`) occurs.

As far as I can tell, here's the main difference and potential pitfall:

- If you dynamically add a control in `Init`, you can access its posted form data in `Load`.
- If you dynamically add a control in `Load`, you have to wait until the postback event (or else access the `HttpRequest.Form` collection directly).

Comment: Very insightful answer. Described "potential" pitfall is very dangerous. I haven't had to solve any difficult problems yet because I have a lot of luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It means that by the time `Control_Load` executes, the postback cycle has come and gone. If you have a control that needs to participate in postback, you need to load it before, so that's why the docs recommend doing it in the `Init` override instead.

If your controls don't participate in postback then you're OK.

Comment: Why would you create a serverside UserControl when you don't plan to use it on server? Apart from that, the postback-cycle has not come and gone in page_load, but for example the viewstate is already loaded.

Comment: The OP is not talking about ViewState, which is always available once it's loaded. The paragraph he's referring to mentions _postback_ operations.

Comment: `ViewState` is part of the _postback data processing_. OP actually wants to know in general what pitfalls there are if adding controls dynamically during page's load event. What does "don't participate in postback" mean? You can read or write UserControl's properties and handle its events even if it's added in page_load. The control's ViewState/ControlState is not an issue because the page ensures that all of the control's events are raised until it has caught up to the current event(including loading ViewState).